# Form as_p, error validation, django signup

Tags: django, forms

I am using form.as_p in my sign.in template. I have noticed that there is information regarding length of password - it requires at least 8 letters. But when I am registrering a user and put a password with 1 letter it does not raise any error. It accepts this, but after all there is impossible to log in with this data. Do you know how can i solve this? I mean how can I raise this error and do not let sign up a user with for short password?

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

    {% block title %}Sign Up{% endblock %}

    {% block content %}
      <h2>Sign up</h2>
      <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button type="submit">Sign up</button>
      </form>
    {% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote my own code like this.
First you need create `forms.py`:

```
class RegisterForm(forms.ModelForm):
    username = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    password1 = forms.CharField(max_length=100, widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(max_length=100, widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = [
            'username',
            'password1',
            'password2',
        ]

    def clean_password2(self):
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get('password1')
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get('password2')
        if len(password) < 8:
            raise ValidationError('Password too short')
        elif password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError('passwords do not match')
        return password2
```

and, then `views.py`:

```
def register_view(request):
    form = RegisterForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        user = form.save(commit=False)
        password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        new_user = authenticate(username=user.username, password=password)
        login(request, new_user)
        return redirect('home_app:index')
    return render(request, 'accounts/forms.html', {'form': form, 'title': 'Sign Up'})
```

Comment: I have read this code and i can not see any line which would require length of password

Comment: Sorry, sorry, i made a change now